# Regex C# - group matches doesn't iterate

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying add a space before capital letters in a word that appears just after a specific word.

Before:

```
[XpTo("GetTheStuff", "XXX")]
```

After:

```
[XpTo("Get The Stuff", "XXX")]
```

This is my best attempt:
Expression: `(\[XpTo\(")([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)+`
Replace: `$1 $2`
Result: `[XpTo(" Stuff", "XXX")]`

I don't get it why the second group **`([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)`** doesn't 'iterate' and only returns the last occurrence.

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-a-numbered-group): The `$` *number* language element includes the **last** substring matched by the *number* capturing group in the replacement string

Comment: you are right, but how do I use all the matched substrings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the .NET lookbehind that supports variable length patterns:

```
(?<=\[XpTo\("(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]+)+)[A-Z]+[a-z]+
```

Replace with a space and `$&`, the backreference to the whole match value.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5BXpTo%5C%28%22%28%3F%3A%5BA-Z%5D%2B%5Ba-z%5D%2B%29%2B%29%5BA-Z%5D%2B%5Ba-z%5D%2B&i=%5BXpTo%28%22GetTheStuff%22%2C%20%22XXX%22%29%5D&r=%20%24%26)

**Details**

- `(?<=\[XpTo\("(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]+)+)` - a positive lookbehind that requires its patterns to match immediately to the left of the current position:

  - `\[XpTo\("` - a literal `[XpTo("` text
  - `(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]+)+` - one or more sequences of
  - `[A-Z]+[a-z]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters followed with one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `[A-Z]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters

Comment: How can I then write the replacement?

Comment: @xkzt0 I already explained that: a space + `$&`, `" $&"`. See the regex demo substitution string.